# Why am I getting "Error in [: subscript out of bounds" when I running the plot function?

Tags: r, shiny

The below MWE code works as intended, except for the plot function at the end of the below code. When running this, I should first get the plot of default values (60 periods on x-axis, 0.20 on the y-axis) --- but I instead get "Error in [: subscript out of bounds". However, when I click the SHOW VECTOR button (in the `renderUI` function), I get the correct initial default plot which can then be modified as intended via changes to the 2nd matrix that pops up in the sidebar panel after clicking SHOW VECTOR.

Also, when I comment out the line in the `renderUI` section, `req(input$showPerfVectorBtn)`, the correct default plot initially pops up as it should EXCEPT that commenting out this line nullifies the SHOW VECTOR button option, showing the vector input grid from the start. The vector input grid (2nd matrix) needs to be hidden at initialization until the user clicks the SHOW VECTOR button. The HIDE button works fine.

What have I done wrong in that plot function? I know it has something to do with correctly initializing the values for the base default plot, but I've tried different things and can't get it to work. The `tagList` function in the `renderUI` section does properly initialize values needed for the `vector.final` custom function called in the `renderPlot` function, that's why clicking the SHOW VECTOR function generates the correct default plot.

Code:

```
library(shiny);library(shinyMatrix);library(shinyjs)

matrix1.input <- function(x) {
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1, dimnames = list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL)),
    rows = list(extend = FALSE,  names = TRUE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric")}

matrix2.input <- function(x,y,z){
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = matrix(c(y,z),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("Y","Z"))),
    rows = list(extend = TRUE,  names = FALSE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric")}  

matrix.validate <- function(x,y){
  a <- x                                
  a[,1][a[,1]>y] <- y                   
  b <- diff(a[,1,drop=FALSE])
  b[b<=0] <- NA
  b <- c(1,b)
  a <- cbind(a,b)
  a <- na.omit(a)
  a <- a[,-c(3),drop=FALSE]
  return(a)}

vector <- function(X,Y,Z){                                            
  a <- rep(NA, X)
  a[Y] <- Z
  a[seq_len(min(Y)-1)] <- a[min(Y)]
  if(max(Y) < X){a[seq(max(Y)+1, X, 1)] <- 0}
  a <- approx(seq_along(a)[!is.na(a)],a[!is.na(a)],seq_along(a))$y
  b <- seq(1:X)
  c <- data.frame(X = b, Z = a)
  return(c)}

vector.final <- function(x,y){vector(x,matrix.validate(y,x)[,1],matrix.validate(y,x)[,2])}

### Shiny code ###
ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model"),
    sidebarPanel(
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==2",
               sliderInput('periods','',min=1,max=120,value=60),
               matrix1.input("base_input"),
               
               # Action buttons to conditionally show/hide performance vectors:
                 useShinyjs(),
                 actionButton('showPerfVectorBtn','Show vector'), 
                 actionButton('hidePerfVectorBtn','Hide vector'),
                 uiOutput("Vectors")),
    ), # close sidebar panel
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Dynamic", value=2,helpText("Dynamic model"),plotOutput("graph1")),
          id = "tabselected")
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  # --- Set reactive input variables 
  periods       <- reactive(input$periods)
  base_input    <- reactive(input$base_input)
  vector_input  <- reactive(input$vector_input)
  
  # --- Link first row of vector input grids to base_input matrix
  observeEvent(input$periods|input$base_input,{
    updateMatrixInput(session,"vector_input", 
                      value=matrix(c(input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]),1,2, 
                                   dimnames=list(NULL, c("Y","Z")))
    ) # close update matrix
  }) # close observe event
  
  # --- Show performance vector if user elects
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    req(input$showPerfVectorBtn)
    tagList(matrix2.input("vector_input",input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]))
  }) # close render UI

  # Action buttons to conditionally show/hide performance vectors:
  observeEvent(input$showPerfVectorBtn, {shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$hidePerfVectorBtn, {shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})

  output$graph1 <- renderPlot({plot({vector.final(periods(),vector_input())})})

}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Could it be a problem with your functions? It's hard to follow what you're trying to do there, but have you checked that `vector.final(()` produces something logical based on your initialized values? Another idea is to play around with various combinations of `ignoreNULL` and `ignoreInit` (see [help page](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.0/observeEvent.html)]

Comment: Absolutely right, it is a problem with the functions. The original MWE code above tries to force matrices of differing dimensions through the same matrix.validate function, the renderPlot incorrectly calls the functions, etc. I'm also looking into a flowcharting tool so I can  better document things, as I quickly forgot how those functions work. It took me a long time to see the problem with "function chaining".  I had to reconstruct the functions one by one. Will post a complete fix soon, I'm almost done.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below resolved code, addressing the original question above. Main problem with original code is with the defined functions at the top; they had to be refined to address the differently-dimensioned input matrices that should be being used in calculations. Also `renderPlot` was incorrectly calling on those same defined functions; it is now correct in the below "fixed" code. I had to re-familiarize myself with the defined functions to see where the errors were. This was a bit much of an ask for anyone other than the drafter of those functions. Removing `req` per the comment sent me down the right path because it's usage was covering up the underlying issues with the defined functions, in most usage cases.

```
library(shiny);library(shinyMatrix);library(shinyjs)

matrix1.input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1, dimnames = list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL)),
    rows = list(extend = FALSE,  names = TRUE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric")}

matrix2.input <- function(x,y,z){
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = matrix(c(y,z),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("Y","Z"))),
    rows = list(extend = TRUE,  names = FALSE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric")}  

matrix.validate <- function(x,y){
  a <- y  
  a[,1][a[,1]>x] <- x 
  b <- diff(a[,1,drop=FALSE])
  b[b<=0] <- NA              
  b <- c(1,b)                
  a <- cbind(a,b)
  a <- na.omit(a)
  a <- a[,-c(3),drop=FALSE]
  return(a)}

vector.base <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x)
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)
  return(c)}

vector.multi <- function(x,y,z){                                            
  a <- rep(NA, x)
  a[y] <- z
  a[seq_len(min(y)-1)] <- a[min(y)]
  if(max(y) < x){a[seq(max(y)+1, x, 1)] <- 0}
  a <- approx(seq_along(a)[!is.na(a)],a[!is.na(a)],seq_along(a))$y
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, z = a)
  return(c)}

vector.multiFinal <- function(x,y){vector.multi(x,matrix.validate(x,y)[,1],matrix.validate(x,y)[,2])}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model"),
    sidebarPanel(
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==2",
                       sliderInput('periods','',min=1,max=120,value=60),
                       matrix1.input("base_input"),
                       useShinyjs(),
                       actionButton('showBtn','Show vector'), 
                       actionButton('hideBtn','Hide vector'),
                       uiOutput("Vectors")),
    ), # close sidebar panel
    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Dynamic", value=2,plotOutput("graph1")),
        id = "tabselected")
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  periods       <- reactive(input$periods)
  base_input    <- reactive(input$base_input)
  vector_input  <- reactive(input$vector_input)

  observeEvent(input$periods|input$base_input,{
    updateMatrixInput(session,"vector_input", 
                      value=matrix(c(input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]),1,2, 
                                   dimnames=list(NULL, c("Y","Z")))
    ) # close update matrix
  }) # close observe event
  
  # --- Show performance vector if user elects
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    req(input$showBtn)
    tagList(matrix2.input("vector_input",input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]))
  }) # close render UI
  
  observeEvent(input$showBtn, {shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$hideBtn, {shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})
  
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot(
    if(input$showBtn == 0)
      plot(vector.base(periods(),input$base_input[1,1]),type="b")
    else
      plot(vector.multiFinal(periods(),matrix.validate(periods(),vector_input())),type="b")
    ) # close render plot
 }) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out. You can accept your own answer as correct to indicate that the problem is solved, or even remove the question and answer both, since in the end the problem wasn't related to the `shiny` app at all. Your choice.